# Android: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1

Tags: android, initialization, audiorecord

I developed an android-app (Home Noise Alert) and it works fine on many devices. But now I got an error report from a user who uses following device:

```
ANDROID_VERSION=6.0.1
PHONE_MODEL=HTC One A9
```

A kind User send me an error report, but I don't understand it. He got this error if he started the app.

This is the error log:

```
02-05 18:42:41.501 E/AudioRecord( 6200): AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
02-05 18:42:41.505 E/AudioRecord-JNI( 6200): Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
02-05 18:42:41.505 E/android.media.AudioRecord( 6200): Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-05 18:42:41.505 E/android.media.AudioRecord( 6200): startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
```

I believe this bug occurs if a microphone is blocked by another app, do some body have any experience with such errors?

Answer (score 6):

Go into your Settings/Apps/YourApp/Permissions and enable the microphone

Comment: Buddy helped like a charm

Answer (score 3):

On recent Android versions, it seems that repushing the apk from Android Studio after changing the permissions in the manifest doesn't actually change the permission in the app settings.  This is why the above answer worked for me.  I had built an application without the RECORD_AUDIO permission in my manifest, and seen the permission error in my log (along with the errors in the OP).  I added the permission to my manifest and reran the application on device, the permission error in the log was no longer there but I still got the errors in the OP.  I went to my System, Applications, Application Manager -> MyApp -> Permissions, and saw that Record Audio was listed but still turned off.  Manually turning that on fixed it.

I imagine (but haven't confirmed) that if I built the correct permission into my manifest in the first place, this would have just worked for me.  Alternatively, uninstalling my app from the device, and then reinstalling, might fix too, but I haven't tried that either.

Comment: This answer has been reviewed by a moderator.